# How can I write a function to modify the word before or after the cursor?

Tags: interactive, words, thing-at-point

I have written the following function to shorten a string:

```lisp
 (defun shorten-hash ()
  "Shorten string (forward or backwards) to eight characters;
   particularly for shortening hashes"
  (interactive)
  (let* ((bounds (bounds-of-thing-at-point 'word))
         (word (if bounds
                   (buffer-substring (car bounds) (cdr bounds))
                 nil))
         (substring (if (and word (>= (- (cdr bounds) (car bounds)) 7))
                        (substring word 0 8)
                      nil)))
    (if substring
        (progn
          (delete-region (car bounds) (cdr bounds))
          (insert substring))
      (message "Cannot shorten word to eight characters"))))

(global-set-key (kbd "C-c M-f") 'shorten-hash)
```

However, I would like to modify this to work with two key bindings, <kbd>C-c M-f</kbd> *and* <kbd>C-c M-f</kbd>, which works in the same way that <kbd>M-BKSP</kbd> vs <kbd>M-d</kbd> works.  That is, <kbd>C-c M-f</kbd> will shorten the word after the cursor, and <kbd>C-c M-b</kbd> shortens the word *before* the cursor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've written the following solution to my question, but I am sure someone else will have a better way of doing it.

```lisp
(defun shorten-hash (word-motion-func)
  "Shorten string (forward or backwards) to eight characters; 
particularly for shortening hashes"
  (let* ((point-start (point))
         (point-stop (progn (funcall word-motion-func) (point)))
         (word (buffer-substring  point-start point-stop)))
    (if (> (length word) 8)
        (progn (delete-region point-start point-stop)
               (insert (substring word 0 8)))
      (message "Cannot shorten word to eight characters"))))

(defun shorten-hash-forward ()
  (interactive)
  (shorten-hash 'forward-word))

(defun shorten-hash-backward ()
  (interactive)
  (shorten-hash 'backward-word))

(global-set-key (kbd "C-c M-f") 'shorten-hash-forward)
(global-set-key (kbd "C-c M-b") 'shorten-hash-backward)
```